# docker buildx failed to build amd64 image in system with architecture arm64

Tags: docker, buildx

I am trying to build a docker image with command

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -f .devcontainer/Dockerfile .
```

it fails with error ERROR: unexpected end of JSON input

however docker build and run does not fail

what could this error mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is just a syntax error when specifying the architecture.

It would need to be this instead:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 ...
```